# What causes this type mismatch when applying a functor?

Tags: types, ocaml, signature, functor

I have the following files:

**SetMaker.mli**

```
module type Element = sig
  type t
  val create : 'a -> t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val to_string : t -> string
end

module type Set = sig
  type t
  val empty : unit -> t
end

module Make (M : Element) : Set with type t = (M.t list)
```

**SetMaker.ml**

```
module type Element = sig
  type t
  val create : 'a -> t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val to_string : t -> string
end

module type Set = sig
  type t
  val empty : unit -> t
end

module Make (M:Element) = struct
  type t = M.t list
  let empty () = []
end
```

**main.ml**

```
open Mylib

module IntEl : SetMaker.Element with type t = int = struct 
  type t = int
  let create (x:int) : t = x
  let compare x y = 
    if x < y then -1
    else if x = y then 0 
    else 1
  let to_string = string_of_int 
end
;;
```

I think some of that is possibly more verbose than it has to be but I just tried throwing around extra declarations just to see if it wouldn't fix things or perhaps give more information in the error message.  In fact, in a related question ([OCaml Type Mismatch Error with Functor-Based Dictionary Insertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77554246/ocaml-type-mismatch-error-with-functor-based-dictionary-insertion)) putting an extra type declaration solved that issue but doesn't seem to solve it here.

When I try to compile I get the error

```
Error: Signature mismatch:
       ...
       Values do not match:
         val create : t -> t
       is not included in
         val create : 'a -> t
       The type t -> t is not compatible with the type 'a -> t
       Type t is not compatible with type 'a 
       File "lib/SetMaker.mli", line 3, characters 2-22: Expected declaration
       File "bin/main.ml", line 5, characters 6-12: Actual declaration
```

I'm quite confused by that because I thought `'a` was supposed to be a type variable which would be compatible with any type used consistently.  So I would think `'a` could be of type `t` whatever that type is.

Comment: Why does `Element` have a `create` function?

Comment: @Chris ah, I thought something like that might be needed to tell the compiler how to interpret a value -- but I think I may be able to see, in light of octachron's answer, how this should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a specification, the function type `'a -> t` is stating that the function accepts arguments of any type `'a` and returns a `t`.

The only values of this type are functions that ignore the first argument and can be rewritten as

```ml
let f _ = g ()
```

for some function `g`.
For instance:

```ml
module M: sig
  val f : 'a -> int 
  val f': 'a -> int
end = struct
  let f _ = 0
  let r = ref 2
  let f' _ = incr r; !r
end
```

At a higher-level, a `Set` module probably doesn't need to know how to create new elements, thus it is probably simpler to remove the underspecified function `create` from the `Element` module type.

```
module type Element = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t -> int
  val to_string : t -> string
end
```